# Add a column to an select SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a sql query that selects certain attributes from a table, it looks as follows:

```
SELECT [pk], [TagGenNo], [Enabled] FROM [TagNumbers]
```

Now I want my sql query to return the data with an additional column called selected which is defaulted to false and is of type bit / boolean.

So it will return a result as follows:

```
pk    TagGenNo    Enabled    Selected
100   03          1          0
101   023         0          0
```

Comment: Do you want a hard coded '0', or is there some way that the new derived column can be computed from data?

Comment: Hard coded 0,
When my program loads this query into its data set, it will then alter this column when I select a row, this way when I click my button, I know which entities they have selected.

Comment: I agree with [`lc.` (below)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23857537/2055998) you need to reconsider your design.  If you want something solely for back-end than create / default it right there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you just want a column full of zeroes in your results. If so, just select a constant:

```
SELECT [pk], [TagGenNo], [Enabled], CAST(0 AS bit) AS [Selected] FROM [TagNumbers]
```

---

As a side note, while this does have its applications (e.g. inserting data into another table which does not have a default value) you may want to think twice about your application's architecture. If the value of this column is *always* a constant and never persisted back to the database, there is really no benefit to generating this value at the database side and having to send a whole bunch of zeroes back through the wire. (Not to mention it strongly couples the persistence layer with the controller or presentation layer).

Following your comment, I would suggest to keep a boolean property `Selected` of each object in the object itself, with a default of `false` at construction time. This way your database doesn't have to know anything about "object selection"